# Xamarin Android: Receiving Firebase Notification Token

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, notifications, token

I can receive refresh token from onRefreshToken when the application first installed. When I recompiled and run the application without removing the application (eg. Update), the application no longer receives the notification from Azure Notification Hub. I suspected the token was changed but onRefreshToken was not called.

```
if (FirebaseApp.GetInstance(FirebaseApp.DefaultAppName) == null)
        {
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .SetApplicationId(GetString(Resource.String.fcmAppId))
                .SetApiKey(GetString(Resource.String.fcmApiKey))
                .SetGcmSenderId(GetString(Resource.String.fcmGCMSenderId))
                .Build();

            FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Android.App.Application.Context, options);
        }


    [Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseInstanceIdService";

    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Settings.NotificationToken = refreshedToken;
        Settings.HasInstalledWithNH = false;
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to call FirebaseInstanceId.Instance and delete the token so the app can receive a new one.